# Prove that $\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{ab}{a^2+b^2+3c^2}+\frac{1}{2}\geq0$

Tags: inequality, contest-math

> Let $a$, $b$ and $c$ be real numbers such that $a^2+b^2+c^2\neq0$. Prove that:
>   $$\frac{ab}{a^2+b^2+3c^2}+\frac{bc}{b^2+c^2+3a^2}+\frac{ca}{c^2+a^2+3b^2}+\frac{1}{2}\geq0$$

The equality occurs for example for $c=0$, $a=1$ and $b=-1$ and the inequality seems nice enough, but I don't see an easy proof.

My ugly proof.

Let $a+b+c=3u$, $ab+ac+bc=3v^2$, where $v^2$ can be negative, and $abc=w^3$.

Hence, we need to prove that
$$\prod_{cyc}(a^2+b^2+c^2+2a^2)+2\sum_{cyc}ab(a^2+b^2+c^2+2a^2)(a^2+b^2+c^2+2b^2)\geq0$$ and we see that
$$\prod_{cyc}(a^2+b^2+c^2+2a^2)+2\sum_{cyc}ab(a^2+b^2+c^2+2a^2)(a^2+b^2+c^2+2b^2)=$$
$$=32w^6+A(u,v^2)w^3+B(u,v^2),$$
which says that the following inequality is a linear inequality of $w^3$.
$$\prod_{cyc}(a^2+b^2+c^2+2a^2)+2\sum_{cyc}ab(a^2+b^2+c^2+2a^2)(a^2+b^2+c^2+2b^2)\geq$$
$$\geq\frac{32}{(3-3k+m)^2}\left(\sum_{cyc}\left(a^3+k(a^2b+a^2c)+\frac{m}{3}abc\right)\right)^2.$$
Thus, it remains to prove the last inequality for an extremal value of $w^3$,

which happens for equality case of two variables

and since the last inequality is homogeneous and even degree,

we can assume $b=c=1$, which gives
$$(a^2+4)(3a^4+12a^3+16a^2+8a+16)\geq\frac{32(a^3+2+2k(a^2+a+1)+ma)^2}{(3-3k+m)^2}.$$
Easy to see that for $a=-2$ the last inequality is equality

and if we wish to get multiplier $(a+2)^2$ we need that 
$$\left((a^2+4)(3a^4+12a^3+16a^2+8a+16)-\frac{32(a^3+2+2k(a^2+a+1)+ma)^2}{(3-3k+m)^2}\right)'_{a=-2}=0,$$
which gives $k=3$ and it remains to find a value of $m$ for which the inequality
$$(a^2+4)(3a^4+12a^3+16a^2+8a+16)\geq\frac{32(a^3+2+6(a^2+a+1)+ma)^2}{(m-6)^2}$$
is true.

It turns out that $m=-1$ is valid because 
$$ (a^2+4)(3a^4+12a^3+16a^2+8a+16)\geq\frac{32(a^3+2+6(a^2+a+1)-a)^2}{49}$$
it's $(a+2)^2(115a^4-256a^3+464a^2-520a+272)\geq0$, which is obvious.

I am looking for an alternative nice proof for this nice inequality.

Thank you!

Comment: Did you try with $a=\cos x\cdot \sin y$,  $b= \cos x \cdot \cos y$ and $c= \sin x$?

Comment: @John Watson I think it gives a very ugly inequality.

Comment: Is it any better if you write it like this: $$\frac{(a+b)^2+3c^2}{a^2+b^2+3c^2}+\frac{(b+c)^2+3a^2}{b^2+c^2+3a^2}+\frac{(c+a)^2+3b^2}{c^2+a^2+3b^2}\geq 2$$

Comment: $bw$ helps here

Comment: @bamboo_jjvy271 Our variables are reals. Are you sure that it will help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Setting $p=a+b+c,\,q=ab+bc+ca,\,r=abc.$ The inequality equivalent to
$$ 2 \sum ab(b^2+c^2+3a^2)(c^2+a^2+3b^2) + (a^2+b^2+3c^2)(b^2+c^2+3a^2)(c^2+a^2+3b^2) \geqslant 0,$$
or
$$32r^2+p^2(3p^4-12p^2q+16q^2) \geqslant 12p^3r.$$
Because $32r^2 \geqslant 0,$ so we will show that
$$p^2(3p^4-12p^2q+16q^2) \geqslant 12p^3r.$$
But $3pr \leqslant q^2.$ It's remains to prove that
$$p^2(3p^4-12p^2q+16q^2) \geqslant 4p^2q^2,$$
equivalent to
$$3p^2(p^2-2q)^2 \geqslant 0.$$
Which is true.

**Note.** From this proof, we can write inequality as
$$ 32a^2b^2c^2+3(a+b+c)^2(a^2+b^2+c^2)^2+2(a+b+c)^2 \sum a^2(b-c)^2\geqslant 0.$$

Comment: I checked your solution. It's true. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way.

Since the inequality will not change if we multiply all $a,b,c$ by the same number $k\neq 0$ then we can assume that $a^2+b^2+c^2=2$. This makes the computation much simpler. Indeed, the inequality becomes
$$\dfrac{ab}{c^2+1}+\dfrac{bc}{a^2+1} +\dfrac{ca}{b^2+1}+1 \geq 0$$
Which is equivalent to
$$\displaystyle\sum_{abc} \big(ab(a^2+1)(b^2+1) \big)+ (a^2+1)(b^2+1)(c^2+1) \geq 0$$

We have 
$$RHS=\displaystyle\sum_{abc} \big( a^3b^3+ab(a^2+b^2)+ab \big) +a^2b^2c^2+a^2b^2+b^2c^2+c^2a^2+a^2+b^2+c^2+1$$
$$=a^3b^3+b^3c^3+c^3a^3+3(ab+bc+ca)-abc(a+b+c)+ a^2b^2c^2+a^2b^2+b^2c^2+c^2a^2+a^2+b^2+c^2+1$$
$$=(ab+bc+ca+1)(a^2b^2+b^2c^2+c^2a^2-abc(a+b+c))+4a^2b^2c^2+(a+b+c)^2+ab+bc+ca+1$$

Since $a^2+b^2+c^2=2$, $ab+bc+ca +1 \geq 0$ so $RHS\geq 0$, which we want to prove. The equality happens if $a+b+c=0$,$abc=0$ and $ab+bc+ca=-1$, i.e., $(a,b,c)=(1,0,-1)$ and permutations of it.

Comment: I think your solution follows from the Nguyenhuyen_AG's solution. In any case, thank you!

Comment: I did not follow his idea. Btw you’re welcome and the inequality is very nice. ^^